# Doctrine LIKE case insensitive

Tags: doctrine

is it possible to make a search with Doctrine case insensitive?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This depends mainly on your Database-Server. A LIKE with MySQL is case insensitive a like with PostgreSQL is case sensitive. But you can help yourself with something like this:

```php
$pattern = strtolower('HEllO WorlD');
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->select('u.username')
    ->from('User u')
    ->where("LOWER(u.username) LIKE ?", $pattern);
```

Comment: And what about indexes on username column?

Answer (score 7):

Also, you can try:

```
$queryBuilder->where('LOWER(b.title) LIKE LOWER(:query)')
        ->setParameter('query', '%' . $query . '%');
```

**Important:** After converting a string that contains special characters to lower case with strtolower(), the special characters don’t appear correct.

Comment: You can prevent the PHP `strtolower` from breaking with using the `mb_strtolower` function. Of course PHP needs to contain the mbstring module for this to work. Although, I do not know if the database is quicker with `LOWER` or if PHP is at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Other thing you can do is:

```
$qb->andWhere($qb->expr()->like('lower(o.name)', ':name'));

$qb->setParameter('name', '%'. strtolower($search) . '%');
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to have a canonized username column, in that column you can store the lowercase version of the username column and any other canonization process you want to do and search and index that column instead of the username column, then just do

```
->where("u.canonic_username) LIKE ?", $pattern);
```

That way you can use indexes and all of that.